# Starting an activity from fragment causes NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I have an activity contains ViewPager with fragments

MainActivity.java :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @BindView(R.id.viewPager) ViewPager viewPager;
    private ViewPagerAdapter pagerAdapter;

    private void initView() {
        pagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(pagerAdapter);
    }
}
```

InfoFragment.Java :

```
public class InfoFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_info, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, root);
        initView();
        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ContactActivity.class);
        intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(MainActivity.CONTACT_LIST, (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) contactList);
        startActivityForResult(intent, CONTACT_ACTIVITY);
    }
}
```

When executing the onClick method exactly at this line:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ContactActivity.class);
```

This exception occurs

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:77)
at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:4618)
at com.swazer.smares.ui.fragments.InfoFragment$1.onClick(InfoFragment.java:128)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5217)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20983)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6117)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Anybody has any idea why this happening?

Comment: there should be a line with `android.content.Context.getPackageName()` in your MainActivity. check it.

Comment: Try it as `Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ContactActivity.class);` because as in log means `getActivity()` returning `null`

Comment: #isnotmenow I think getPackageName() is defined in Context class and it shouldn't be in my activity

Comment: instead of using `getActivity()`  you should use `getApplicationContext()` or `getContext()`.

Comment: getContext() returns null too, and getApplicationContext() is not exist in Fragment

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the following code:

**1)** Try this code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ContactActivity.class);
```

**2)** Add this to your java files:

***MainActivity.java..***

```
public static Context cxt;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    cxt = this;

    @BindView(R.id.viewPager) ViewPager viewPager;
    private ViewPagerAdapter pagerAdapter;

    private void initView() {
        pagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(pagerAdapter);
    }
}
```

***InfoFragment.java:***

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.cxt, ContactActivity.class);
        intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(MainActivity.CONTACT_LIST, (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) contactList);
        startActivityForResult(intent, CONTACT_ACTIVITY);
    }
```

Comment: Any idea way getActivity() would return null?

Comment: I think it is returning null because you are calling that method from the fragment. so it do not assign a value to that method. You have to the context which has a value

Comment: I'm still testing all possible cases but i think v.getContext() is working fine

Comment: Sadly nothing seems working the v.getContext() didn't work on Samsung Tab A